# android onClick not firing?

Tags: java, android, onclick

**EDIT**: onClick is working properly now. The issue was that the button was trying to fire the onClick from the Parent class. now that is fixed. Of course that means a new issue is happening, that is the onActivityResult is never getting called.

So I am not really sure what the hell is going on, when I hit the button nothing happens, nothing in logcat, nothing, as if there is not code, but I am pretty sure this is written correctly, any thoughts?

```
public class myClass extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.store_selector);
    Button getStore = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getStore);

    getStore.setOnClickListener(buttonGetStoreOnClickListener);
}

Button.OnClickListener buttonGetStoreOnClickListener
= new Button.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View arg0) {


    Intent intent = new Intent("com.blah.Blah.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.setPackage("com.blah.Blah");
    intent.putExtra("com.blah.Blah.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
};
};  


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    if (requestCode == 0)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            Log.i("debug tag", "contents: "+contents+" format: "+format);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Ads.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("key", contents);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_ads);

            // Handle successful scan
        }
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            // Handle cancel
            Log.i("xZing", "Cancelled");
        }
    }
}


};
```

Comment: have you added some breakpoints and stepped through to see what happens?

Comment: Add a log on your onClick for buttonGetStoreOnClickListener and add a log before you check if (requestCode == 0), it will help.

Comment: Not that it should matter but try using View.OnClickListener instead of Button.OnClickListener. I do not believe this should make a difference but I have never used the method from the Button class always from the View class. Other than that I do not see any obvious reason for your code to fail.

Comment: now I am getting things to hit, however onActivityResult is never getting called

Comment: You are probably starting it incorrectly then, since it would return some sort of result value if it ran in the first place

Comment: Or maybe you have not added the activity to your manifest that you are trying to start.

Answer (score 0):

This is the class you need to import:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

And this is the method you should have:

```
OnClickListener onButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // Your code here   
  }
};
```

Test it and let me know if it worked.

Regards

Comment: It was posted while I was writing my response.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you got the right button with **Button getStore = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getStore);** ?

If yes, then it can be something that sometimes happens to me sometimes.
When this happens, my logcat doesn't show anything. What I do to solve this, is to open the Devices view (Window, show view, other, Android, Devices) and select my device. Then when I look at the logcat again, everything's there.